# How to make js/javascript retrieve the specific html option value inside a django python forloop

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

So I want to get the option currently selected on my looped option value, but it only keeps getting the last index of the loop whenever I press submit.

**views.py**

```
def editGrp(request):       
JSONer = {}
parsedData = urlparse.urlparse(request.get_full_path())
pkid = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['pkid'][0])
print(pkid)
groupid = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['groupid'][0])
if User.objects.filter(id=pkid).count() > 0 and Group.objects.filter(id=groupid).count() > 0:
    print(pkid)
    print(groupid)
    userID = User.objects.filter(id=pkid)[0]
    userID.profile.group_id = groupid
    print(userID.username)
    userID.save(force_update=True)
return HttpResponseRedirect(json.dumps(JSONer))
```

**specific code inside my "admin.html"**

The loop is for listing all the users who aren't inside the specific group

```
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Add Members:</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <select name="employeeName" id="employeeLocation" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
    {% for user in users %}
      {% ifnotequal user.profile.group.id groups.id %}
        <option name="userGroup" id="userGroup-{{ user.id }}" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.username}}</option>
      {% endifnotequal %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

**submit button in admin.html**

```
<button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="editGrpAjax('userGroup-{{user.id}}', {{groups.id}})" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

**javascript code**

```
<script>
    function editGrpAjax(id,groupid){
      var newid = document.getElementById(id).value;
      var newgroupid = document.getElementById('groupid-' + groupid).value;
        $.ajax({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/editGrp/?pkid='+ newid + "&groupid=" + newgroupid, 
            success: function(result){

              // insert success message here
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It keeps getting the last value of the loop, and not the one that is currently  selected or highlighted in the option value upon submit.

Comment: "It keeps getting the last value of the loop". What is "it"? I guess maybe you mean the editGrpAjax function? In that case, how are these two snippets of code linked? Can't see anywhere where editGrpAjax is being called, or what is being passed to it, so it's impossible to say why it might be receiving the wrong values. You mention "pressing submit", but that's not shown either. I think you missed out the most important bit of the code.

Comment: Yeah forgot to add it, my mistake. Just updated it now!

Comment: By "it", i meant the "id" of userGroup that is being retrieved by the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother passing `id` and `groupid` into your function. Like you said - it always only receives the last values looped, because that's hard-coded based on the `userGroup-{{user.id}}', {{groups.id}}` string. That string is set by the server at page load, and never changes during the life of the page.

If you want to find the option which is currently selected, simply do:

```
var newid = document.getElementById("employeeLocation").value;
```

The `value` of the `<select>` will be the value of the currently selected `<option>`.